# Length of array of files not correct in shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=../folder/files/*

echo "Total files in array : ${#FILES[@]}"
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing file $f"
done
```

In `../folder/files/` I have 3 files and the for loops through them properly. However, the number of files in array is incorrect. It returns 18 instead of 3.

I am sure there are not any other files in the folder.

Concretely for my purpose, the output is:

```
$ sh run_benchmark.sh 
Total files in array : 18
Running benchmark for file ../benchmark/cfg/2_150.cfg
Running benchmark for file ../benchmark/cfg/2_300.cfg
Running benchmark for file ../benchmark/cfg/2_500.cfg
```

What is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `FILES` is not an array. If you wanted that you meant `FILES=(../folder/files/*)`.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried that and I get the error: `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: That's because you are using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `bash` and it doesn't support arrays.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh, I switched to `bash` and now the number of files is OK but the loop only shows the first. Sorry, I'm kind of newbie with scripting.

Comment: You need `"${FILES[@]}"` to expand the array values in the loop. That being said if you don't care about the count ahead of time (or at all) just stick the glob in the `for` line directly and forget the variable entirely.

Comment: @EtanReisner what do you mean exactly? Could you please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless for some special reason you need arrays, don't bother yourself with arrays, simply do:

```
for f in ../path/*
do
    echo "==$f=="
done
```

Using @EtanReisner comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=(../benchmark/cfg/*)

n=0
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    let n++
    echo "Processing file($n from ${#FILES[@]})  ==$f=="
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that is not my problem. I was able to do that before. I am trying to be a bit fancy and show a counter (`file 1 out of 20`).

Comment: You need to quote `"${FILES[@]}"` in case any of the globbed files had any spaces or other globbing/metacharacters in them.

Comment: Just one last thing, as @EtanReisner pointed out, that works with `bash` not with `sh`. Thank you!

Comment: @JaviV - ok corrected - but, on my system `/bin/sh` is `bash`... (and not `dash`) :)

Answer (score 1):

This line `FILES=../folder/files/*` is not expanding the glob.

You aren't expanding the glob until this line `for f in $FILES`.

I was going to say that when you write `echo "Total files in array : ${#FILES[@]}"` you are asking the shell for the length of the string `../folder/files/*` but that seems to not be the case. I don't know exactly what the shell is doing here (trying to use `FILES` as an array and failing but getting one element (the value of `FILES`?) and reporting `1`?).

Anyway, if you want the glob expansion in an array then you need to use an array.

```
FILES=(../folder/files/*)
```

And then you can use `"${#FILES[@]}"` to get the length and `for f in "${FILES[@]}"` to iterate over the values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Still, in case someone wants to use arrays for some reason:

```
list=( $path/* )
```

that assumes no funny files with spaces, tabs or newlines in the names.

Comment: Quote `"$path"` and it doesn't need to assume any of that.